# Error al importar librerias python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy programando en **python** e instalo librerias y se instalan correctamente, pero cuando las voy a utilizar *Visual Studio* no las reconoce y marca error.

Me viene pasando desde hace un tiempo y no me reconoce las librerias que descargo.

Comment: VSCode no usa necesariamente el mismo intérprete python que el que tú hayas usado para instalar las librerías, si en tu ordenador coexisten varias versiones de python. Tienes que asegurarte de que el python que has usado para instalar las librerías es el mismo que el que después usa VSCode para asistirte en la edición. Puedes cambiar este último con Ctrl+Mayus+P y escribiendo "Python interprete"

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que tengas instaladas las bibliotecas y las importes correctamente, Visual Studio no las va a reconocer debido a que tu VS no cuenta con un soporte para Python y no reconoce una compatibilidad con sus Herramientas de trabajo, por lo que debes instalar nuevamente VS a su versión más reciente y verificar durante el instalador el seleccionar en la pestaña de cargas de trabajo disponibles la que es para el desarrollo de Python, la cual se llama Desarrollo de Python (Python development).

!(https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/python/media/installation-python-workload.png?view=vs-2022)

Nota: La compatibilidad con Python no está actualmente disponible en Visual Studio para Mac, pero está disponible en Mac y Linux a través de Visual Studio Code.

Información completa en: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Eso mismo me sucedía cuando descargaba librerías en el entorno virtual, por más que probaba dichas librerías y me corría sin errores, VSC me las señalaba como errores o no lo reconocía.
Este post me ayudó bastante:

[Visual Studio Code lanza error Import "decouple" could not be resolved al intentar reconocer paquetes instalados en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560139/visual-studio-code-lanza-error-import-decouple-could-not-be-resolved-al-intent)

Técnicamente debes de configurar en VSC con cuál interpretador se debe de alinear Python, de esta manera VSC puede ayudarte a través de las librerías instaladas globalmente, o las de las variables de entorno.