# Visual Studio Code lanza error Import "decouple" could not be resolved al intentar reconocer paquetes instalados en python

Tags: python, visual-studio, virtualenv

Estoy trabajando con entornos virtuales. El caso es que es al momento de instalar los paquetes en dicho entorno virtual, se instalan, el entorno los muestra, pero visual code me dice que no existe dicho paquete. ¿Existe alguna forma de evitar eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen tengo el entorno andando, el paquete de decouple instalado, y sí recibo el print de la función del paquete, sin embargo visual code me lo tiene como error, ya que "no existe".

¿A qué se debe dicho error?

El error que arrojaba era el siguiente:

> Import "decouple" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports).

Comment: si no hay error al ejecutar el programa entonces solo es problema del linter de vscode o que el interprete seleccionado (en vscode) es distinto al de tu entorno

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te dice cuando pasas el cursor por encima? Sólo por el color del subrayado, parece que lo que te dice el linter es que no estás utilizando el módulo que importas. No es un error, tan sólo un aviso.

Comment: @ChemaCortes me arroja el siguiente error: Import "decouple" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports. PD: esta info se puede colocar en comentarios o debo editar la pregunta?

Comment: @blacks5574 debes editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final el problema era tan simple como cambiar la ruta que vsc estaba seleccionando como intérprete.

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Con eso lee directamente el entorno, paquetes y todo.

EDIT:
En la zona inferior derecha de la pantalla de vsc, se distinguen varias informaciones entre estas esta el tipo de lenguaje ocupado (aparece python) y a su derecha la versión de python ocupada, si se da click ahí se abrirá la venta que emerge arriba donde solicita seleccionar el interprete, si se creo bien el entorno virtual debería de aparecer la ruta donde esta la creación del entorno virtual (tal como está seleccionada en la imagen), con eso lee la ruta creada por virtualenv, donde se lee paquetes instalados y se inicia solo el entorno.

PD: Dejo el [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjXxTvhilOM) que me ayudó.

Comment: Describe _como texto_ los pasos a seguir para cambiar la ruta. Ten en cuenta que si el enlace del video llega a romperse, parte fundamental de la respuesta se perderá. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias por la guía <33, no se me había pasado por la cabeza lo del video.